# Flask-Login: How to set current_user to an AnonymousUserMixin object?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

In Flask-Login docs,I read the following statements:

*By default, when a user is not actually logged in, current_user is set to an          AnonymousUserMixin object.*

How to do that? I didn't find the relative code. And if a user is logged in,  is the current_user set to an UserMixin object? If so, how?

Comment: You will need to create a user class, a registration process, a user authentication process before you can use login_user() which sets the current_user in your session. Probably you should use Flask-security if you a looking at a more complete user management package

Comment: If you created an instance of `login_manager = LoginManager()` then you can check anonymous user class by `>>> login_manager.anonymous_user`